# Script to rename files in a Windows subdirectory

Tags: perl, vbscript

Can someone suggest a script to rename a bunch of files in a Windows subdirectory with filenames having spaces to them having underscores. For example if the filename is

```
abc xyz.pdf
```

It should be

```
abc_xyz.pdf
```

Comment: Does it need to recurse into subdirectories of the subdirectory?

Comment: yep recursing into a directory

Comment: What should happen if any of the sub-directory names have spaces in them? Leave as is? Or rename? And if rename, I assume the PARENT directory spaces shouldn't be renamed? E.g. if you are starting in `C:\my docs\pdfs`, and have a file `C:\my docs\pdfs\sci fi\star wars1.pdf`, should it end up as `C:\my docs\pdfs\sci fi\star_wars1.pdf`, `C:\my docs\pdfs\sci_fi\star_wars1.pdf` or `C:\my_docs\pdfs\sci_fi\star_wars1.pdf`? I am assuming #1.

Comment: i want to just change the filenames, not directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl: Use `File::Find` for recursive finding and actioning on files.

Please note that you need to be careful about: Don't rename DIRECTORIES that have underscore, thus `File::Basename`.

```
use File::Find;
use File::Basename;
use File::Spec;
use strict;

find ({ 'wanted' => \&renamefile }, 'X:\my\sub\dir');

sub renamefile {
    my $file = $_;
    return unless (-f $file);   # Don't rename directories!
    my $dirname = dirname($file); # file's directory, so we rename only the file itself.
    my $file_name = basename($file); # File name fore renaming.
    my $new_file_name = $file_name;
    $new_file_name =~ s/ /_/g; # replace all spaces with underscores
    rename($file, File::Spec->catfile($dirname, $new_file_name))
        or die $!; # Error handling - what if we couldn't rename?
}
```

Comment: As noted in the comment on the question, it's unclear what should happen if (1) subdirectories in starting directory have spaces and (2) starting directory has spaces. I assume the answer is "nothing" in the above code; it gets a bit more complicated if you want to rename subdirectories as well but NOT the starting directory.

Comment: Like this.  I need it too.

Answer (score 0):

The following batch file isn't tested, but should work.

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*) do call :rename "%%~ni"
goto :EOF

:rename
set filename=%1
set newname=%filename: =_%
rename "filename" "newname"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the VBSCript script. It will rename files in the folder C:\Test

```
   Dim fso, f, f1, fc, s
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set f = fso.GetFolder("C:\Test")
   Set fc = f.Files
   For Each f1 in fc
      f1.move f1.ParentFolder & "\" & replace(f1.Name, " ", "_")
   Next
```

Comment: I think there might be a syntax error in your `f1.move` line.

Comment: There is no syntax error. It doesn't run through directories though. VBScript does not have a renamefile method. Move is the method for it.

Answer (score 0):

Im still learning PERL so took a stab in this...

```
opendir (curDir, ".");

@filesWithSpaces = grep(/.*\s.*\..*/, readdir (curDir));

foreach $oneFile (@filesWithSpaces){
  $newName = $oneFile;
  $newName =~ s/\ /_/g;
  print "RENAMING: $oneFile -> $newName \n";
  rename($oneFile, $newName);
```

}

Looks fine on my initial tests. Its not recursive though.

Comment: This has several errors, such as renaming spaces in DIRECTORY names.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working VBScript. It does not recurse into subdirectories of the specified directory however.

```
Dim fso
Dim folder
Dim stringToFind
Dim replacement

' Check arguments
If Wscript.Arguments.Count <> 3 Then
    ' Usage
    Wscript.echo "Usage: rename.vbs folder string_to_find replacement"
    WScript.Quit
End If

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set folder = fso.GetFolder(WScript.Arguments(0))

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Folder " & WScript.Arguments(0) & " does not exist."
    WScript.Quit
End If

stringToFind = WScript.Arguments(1)
replacement = WScript.Arguments(2)

For Each file in folder.Files
    fso.MoveFile file.ParentFolder & "\" & file.Name, file.ParentFolder & "\" & Replace(file.Name, stringToFind, replacement)
Next

Set folder = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```