# Recursively navigate subdirectories

Tags: perl, recursion, subdirectory

How can I recursively navigate subdirectories (in Windows) with Perl? Something similar [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665323/script-to-rename-files-in-a-windows-subdirectory), but recursive.

Comment: I think you might need to post the details of this script for anyone to help you.  Also, I'm not sure about the rules on this site but it's best not to encourage people to email you.  Answers should be visible on the site so that other people with your problem can also benefit.

Comment: And what have you done and what are the problems you faced?

Answer (score 6):

> … Even though my purpose it not to
>   rename the files. But I am struck in
>   navigating to Sub directories of the
>   sub directories. …

You will want to read [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html)'s documentation. Especially, the `find` function which will help you traverse directory trees.